# SFML Music multiple channels

Tags: c++, sfml

I have an .ogg file which contains a generated tone on the left channel. If I play this file with a music player I can hear the tone only on the left side, the right side is silent. But when I load and play the same file in C++ with SFML, I can hear the tone on both sides.

I load and play the ogg file like this:

```
sf::Music music;
music.openFromFile("Tone_Left.ogg");
music.play();
```

How can I fix that SFML plays the tone on the left side and not on both sides?

Comment: try setPosition(0, 0)

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work. The default position is 0,0,0 bytheway

Comment: check how many channels it have.

Comment: music.getChannelCount() returns 2, so my guess is that channel 0 is left and 1 is right?

Comment: Yes, your sound is stereo, the best solution is to fix the audio file, or transform it on mono.